# How to update a single row / single cell in a database table using TableAdapters?

Tags: c#, sql-server, tableadapter

I would like to just update a single row / single cell not the entire table in my database (sql-server), is there a way to do this? I have tried the following (assume that I know there is a row with Index 9 in my table so I don't need to check and that I know there is a third column in my table so I don't need to worry about exceptions being thrown for any indexes out of range:

```
// Identifiers used are:
var myTableAdapter = new myDatabaseTableAdapters.myTableTableAdapter();
var myDataTable = myTableAdapter.GetData();
string myQuery = "[Index] = '9'",
    updatedValue = "Some new value";

try 
{
    // Grab the row which needs updating
    var rowForUpdate = (System.Data.DataRow)myDataTable.Select(myQuery)[0];
    rowForUpdate[2] = updatedValue;
    myTableAdapter.Update(rowForUpdate);
}
catch (System.Exception ex) 
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

however this throws the following exception:

```
Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the table you are working with has a primary key, to do this execute the following SQL commnad in sql-server for the column you want to be the primary key (yourColumnName):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.yourTableName
ALTER COLUMN yourColumnName int NOT NULL;
```

this command will make sure that yourColumnName cannot be Nullable which is the case for a primary key. Next execute:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.yourTableName ADD PRIMARY KEY (yourColumnName);
```

this alters the table to now have a primary key for the column you want. Back to Visual Studio 2017 now, in **Solution Explorer**, double-click the myDataBaseDataSet.xsd file, this brings up a visualization of your table schema. Scroll over to yourTableName, it should now have a primary key, right click it (it here means the myTableNameTableAdapter header name) and choose the *Configure...* option. A TableAdapter Configuration Wizard will pop-up. Click the *Advanced Options...* button, you should see that the check box title **Refresh the data table** is now checked. If you looked at this before it is not checked and could not be saved after checking. This allows you to update the table in your database.

The code given above **does not** need to be modified.